# Setting Remote Webdriver to run tests in a remote computer using Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I was trying to setup remote webdriver to run my tests in remote computer, as my application is deployed to my localhost. Using Selenium RC I used host address to run those tests and it worked fine; but I'm having trouble setting up the base class using remote webdriver. I've tried the following code but it has not worked. By the way, I had selenium tests which I am migrating to remote webdriver. I tried webdriver which works fine but couldn't setup the remote webdriver for remote execution. Any help will be appreciated.

```java
public static  String base_url = "http://localhost:8084";     
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();     
proxy.setProxyAutoconfigUrl(base_url);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(capabilities);
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, base_url);
```

Sample grid 2 code which works for firefox but doesn't work on IE9

```java
String hubURL = "http://myip:4444/wd/hub";
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
//capability.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
//capability.setPlatform("WINDOWS");
//capability.setVersion("9.0.4");
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL), capability);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
element.sendKeys("Cheese!");
element.submit();
driver.quit();
```

Error I was receiving when it's IE9 though I specified IE from command mode from node:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : {platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}
Command duration or timeout: 110 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.16.1', revision: '15405', time: '2012-01-05 12:23:11'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.38-13-generic', java.version: '1.6.0_26'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:147)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:113)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:435)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:135)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:94)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:102)
at com.main.SelTest.main(SelTest.java:25)
Caused by: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : {platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}
at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:151)
at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:81)
at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:67)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.WebApplicationHandler.dispatch(WebApplicationHandler.java:473)
at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:568)
at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.WebApplicationContext.handle(WebApplicationContext.java:633)
at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
```

Comment: Please define _"it not working"_ ...

Comment: I meant to say it not running. as i never mentioned who is going to be my host computer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to install a Selenium Server (a Hub) and register your remote WebDriver to it. Then, your client will talk to the Hub which will find a matching WebDriver to execute your test.

You can have a look at [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2) for more information.

Comment: I tried using the instruction described on grid 2 page. everything work fine when it is firefox but it does not work with IE9. Please check above for details

Comment: `System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.38-13-generic', java.version: '1.6.0_26` Do you really try to launch IE9 on a Linux Box ?

Comment: Nop, I hub is a ubuntu box where i deployed my project and trying to run tests on a windows 7 vm with IE9

Comment: On Selenium wiki page i found this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1699&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&start=200) . Another thing Cant i be able to run a remote driver to windows vm from my linux box? or i need a windows box to run another remote windows driver?

Comment: Do not forget to deploy to the node machines the [ChromeDriver](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list) and [InternetExplorerDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list)  (IEDriverServer*.zip) executables to be able to use Chrome and IE. Simply put the two .exe into the %windir%/system32 to be in the path env var.

Comment: Problem with posting a link is that the link can change, it is transient. It's better to post some code and then reference a link.

Answer (score 2):

This issue came for me due to the fact that .. i was running server with selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0 and client registered with selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0 .. When i made both selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0 and ran then things worked fine

Answer (score 0):

By Default the InternetExplorerDriver listens on port "5555". Change your huburl to match that. you can look on the cmd box window to confirm.

Comment: The IE driver doesn't allow remote connections directly. You need to connect to the selenium-server-standalone, which will then connect to the IE driver.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got rid of the error:

> WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find :
>   {platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet
>   explorer, version=11}

In your nodeconfig.json, the **version** must be a String, not an integer.

So instead of using `"version": 11` use `"version": "11"` (note the double quotes).

A full example of a working nodecondig.json file for a RemoteWebDriver:

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "platform": "WIN8_1",
      "browserName": "internet explorer",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
      "version": "11"
    }
    ,{
      "platform": "WIN7",
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 4,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
      "version": "40"
    }
    ,{
      "platform": "LINUX",
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 4,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
      "version": "33"
    }
  ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 3,
    "port": 5555,
    "host": ip,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": {your-ip-address}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to create HubNode(Server) and start the HubNode(Server) from command Line/prompt using Java: `-jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role hub`
- Then bind the node/Client to this Hub using Hub machines IPAddress or Name with any port number >1024. For Node Machine for example: `Java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://HubmachineIPAddress:4444/grid/register -port 5566`

One more thing is that whenever we use Internet Explore or Google Chrome we need to set: `System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",path);`